# Objective C Runtime and Learn Java with Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, runtime

I learned that Objective-C with Cocoa is a compiled language and that Objective C needs Apple Runtime.

First I was confused. *How that can be?* Objective C is a compiled language and it needs Runtime app works with Objective C application?

*If you have knowledge about how it works and difference between JRE and Objective C Runtime please help me.*

I would like to to learn Java with Objective C if it will be good choice. What is your advices about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "learn Java with Objective-C"??  They are two entirely different languages.  They do have some attributes in common, but the differences are far too great to consider that you're learning one with the other (and especially to consider that learning Objective-C will teach you Java).  (And every non-trivial language needs a "runtime".)

Comment: does c++ needs runtime on linux? and I am planning to learn 2nd language with Objective C. will it be easy or hard for me? Advice about it?

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe user2252060 meant that he/she wants to develop mac applications using java instead of Objective-C.

Comment: @user2252060 if you already know either java, C or C++, it will not be hard to learn Objective-C. You can manage it within a few hours. Learning how to properly use the frameworks and how to interact with the system will take longer.

Comment: No :) thanks to all of you to help this newbie. I am not a developer in my professional life but I love programming.  So I am trying to learn Objective C to develop apps on Mac and on iOS. But also I want to learn second language and am asking will it be easy to learn both of them together or not.   I only know Visual Basic.Net

Comment: Keep in mind that Linux, to a degree, *is* a runtime.  It, by default, implements the basic facilities needed to support C, and includes the basic C runtimes.  Other operating systems will have more or less built-in support for specific languages.

Comment: Objective-C is a hard language to learn well.  You really need a good understanding of fundamental programming concepts, at a relatively low level, to learn it without acquiring some serious misunderstandings along the way.  Java is much "friendlier" to novices (but is still non-trivial to learn well).  It's probably best to learn Java first.

Comment: Objective-C is not specific to MAC OS. However, in the [Objective-C runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) apple states: *`The OS X implementation of the Objective-C runtime library is unique to the Mac. For other platforms, the GNU Compiler Collection provides a different implementation with a similar API.`*

Comment: @Jean - Well, Objective-C is pretty specific to Mac and iPhones.  It might be hosted on a few other platforms, but the only serious support for it is on OSx and iOS, and those are the only places it's used for serious development.

Comment: An important thing to understand is that whatever "runtime" you need with a given language is generally supplied with the development system for that language and is more or less automatically included when you "build" your application.  Java is somewhat unique in that you must actually start the "runtime" (run the "java" command) and have it load your app, vs just starting your app.

Comment: @HotLicks You misunderstood me. I was just addressing agulerer's statement Objective C needs Apple Runtime merely by stating facts: Objective-C is not specific to MAC OS, but apple's implementation of the Objective-C runtime is. And there is GNUStep which cannot be ignored. A lot of people have put great amount of efforts in it. It is a very nice project, thought I have never used it myself. I would never qualify their work as `not serious`.

Comment: @Jean - Most developers would not use Objective-C for apps where at least potential portability to OSx/iOS was not important.  If you're developing commercially (which is what I mean by "serious") then portability is usually a major criterion, and C, C++, C#, Java, and probably a couple of others all have a wider range of target platforms than Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of C. When you write Objective-C code and send a message to an instance:

```
[myObject doSomething];
```

the compiler actually calls down an appropriate function such as `objc_msgSend(…)` to achieve the desired effect. So the runtime is more like a specific API (functions and sata structures). The compiler translates your message into calls to this API.

**So, to answer your questions:**

1. Objective-C is not an interpreted language, but runs natively on the
   machine just like any other C or C++ program. The runtime is not an interpreter, but a library of structures and functions.
2. **Cocoa** is a framework and is not required to write an objective-C program.
3. If you are going to program fro MAC or iOS (iPhone, iPad), I would
   recommend you to drop Java and choose Objective-C.

**Recommended readings**:

- [Cocoa Frameworks, The power of Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html)
- [What's the difference between Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435928/whats-the-difference-between-objective-c-and-cocoa)
- [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

> This document describes the OS X Objective-C 2.0 runtime library
>   support functions and data structures. The functions are implemented
>   in the shared library found at */usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib*. This shared
>   library provides support for the dynamic properties of the Objective-C
>   language, and as such is linked to by all Objective-C applications.

**Also recommended:**

- [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Objective-C is the primary programming language you use when writing
>   software for OS X and iOS. **It’s a superset of the C programming
>   language and provides object-oriented capabilities and a dynamic
>   runtime.** Objective-C inherits the syntax, primitive types, and flow
>   control statements of C and adds syntax for defining classes and
>   methods. It also adds language-level support for object graph
>   management and object literals while providing dynamic typing and
>   binding, deferring many responsibilities until runtime.

- [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596809775/ObjC.pdf)

> The Objective-C language defers as many decisions as it can from
>   compile time and link time to runtime. Whenever possible, it
>   dynamically performs operations such as creating objects and
>   determining what method to invoke. This means that the language
>   requires not just a compiler, but also a runtime system to execute the
>   compiled code. The runtime system acts as a kind of operating system
>   for the Objective-C language; it’s what makes the language work.
>   Typically, however, you don’t need to interact with the runtime
>   directly. To understand more about the functionality it offers,
>   though, see Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide.

Comment: Ok I knew that but what is the compile and run process? For example on Mac app is the procedure   compile-link-compile-run on runtime env.? if so Obj-C should be interpreted language with Cocoa. On C++ you only need compiler and than app runs right?

Comment: is runtime like virtual machine on Java?

Comment: Objective-C is not interpreted. Imagine it like C code. When you send a message, the compiler translates it, at compile time, to a call towards a function of the objc_msgSend family. Cocoa, isn't required. It's juste a framework. You don't require it to write objective-C code. Objective-C runs natively on the machine, juste like C or C++ programs.

Comment: Hmm. So is it correct that Objective C compiler translates codes into machine codes. And when Objective C machine codes runs, it needs libraries to create obj instances etc. and this libraries called Objective C runtime right?

Comment: @user2252060 Yes. The runtime is not an interpreter. Just a set of functions and structures. You can even call the functions yourself and use Objective-C objects while only calling C functions. The runtime can be used by including `#import <objc/runtime.h>`. You can check the headers. Also, I made significant changes to my answer, to clarify all that. See [runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to get a clearer picture.

Comment: now I understood well. does c++ have runtime like Objective-C

Comment: @agulerer Yes it does. If you wish to learn Objective-C, I suggest you to check:  [http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/). It is nicely presented.

Comment: I started to read Programming in Objective-C 4th Edition but I was bored after 300 pages and stopped reading, than I started Bignerdranch Objective C book but I did not understand memory management and arc. So I know main things about objective c but not memory management and arc and using selector, and bitwise operations. Where should I learn those?

Comment: @agulerer You should at least learn about using selectors and memory management. You will need them for your first application. There are two main memory management systems: manual reference counting and Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). Pick one. I would advise you to pick ARC since it is the most recent technology. ARC is also enabled by default on all new projects. You will always find somebody like **H2CO3**, **Martin R**, **dasblinkenlight**, **rmaddy**, **bbum**, **Dave DeLong**, **Peter Hosey**, *and many others – me amongst them –*, here to help you along the way.

Comment: @Thank you very much Jean for your help. I will ask question on when I will have questions about ARC and memory management.

Comment: @agulerer You can learn about Objective-C [here](http://virtuousgiant.com/best-way-learn-objective-c/), on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC0CFA8DF2A8A00C65), or [with other tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0CFA8DF2A8A00C65) and learn about ARC memory management [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: is Objective-CProgramming THE BIG NERD RANCH GUIDE  good to learn objective C?

Comment: I have never read any programming books on Objective-C, so I don't have the knowledge to advise you on this one. However, there are lots of resources to help you choose a good book ([such as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431/what-is-the-best-book-for-learning-objective-c)) and I have read lots of good feedback on: [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegas](http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619).

Comment: do i need to know deep understanding of C language to use Objective C on Mac Os X and iOS? Or is it enough to know structs, loops, primitive types, if statements etc. on C?

Comment: You don't need a deep understanding of C. But you need to know about objects, classes, inheritance in general (just the concepts). You will also need to learn about categories and protocols in objective-C. You will probably be using cocoa, so you need to know about general patterns like MVC (model, view, controller) and delegates. Best is to use a book like Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegas. There are examples in code with explanations for all topics. The topics in the book are very useful to start writing your own apps. There are also books for iOS with examples.